# AppleScript How to return first n elements of item in list

Tags: macos, applescript

I have never written anything in AppleScript but I recently got a MBP and started playing around with it just to tweak the touchbar. In a downloaded preset I saw this line:

```
set theArray to every text item of theString
```

I assume that this line appends the entire string (every single character element) to the array.

How I can choose to append only a fixed n number of characters from that string/item, say maybe the first 10 characters of that string?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
set theString to "Ask Different"
set theArray to text items 1 thru 10 of theString
```

> Result:
>     {"A", "s", "k", " ", "D", "i", "f", "f", "e", "r"}

Since you are new to AppleScript, I encourage you to take the time to read though: [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html)

Just so you know, AppleScript does not have *object* designated with the name `array`, it uses [**`list`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDBHIE) instead. It's a minor technicality however, since you're just starting to learn, its best you know what it's called within the AppleScript Language.

So, instead of using the variable `theArray`, I'd choose to name it `theList`, or more specifically I'd add an additional qualifier. For example, `theCharList`, or whatever is appropriate so as I read through the *code* I write, I readily know what the *variable* is for.